# android calendar permission issue

Tags: codenameone

I am trying to access the android device calendar, which fails with this exception
[image]

I added this exact build hint to the codenameone_settings.properties file:

```
codename1.arg.android.xpermissions=<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALENDAR"/> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CALENDAR"/>
```

Is there something I am missing?

Comment: in which device and which android version have you tested it?

Comment: Samsung S7, Android Nougat

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is caused by the new Android security permission in API level 23.

You can set your app to use API level 21 by adding the build hint below and `DeviceCalendar` should work.

```
android.targetSDKVersion=21
```

> *Remember to always **Upvote**, **Mark as answer**, or **leave a comment** when another user answers your question. That's the only reward they get for helping you to solve a problem.*

Comment: FYI we just updated the calendar cn1lib with support for automatic permissions and API level 23. This is experimental though...

Answer (score 1):

please refer this link hope it will help you
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/codenameone-discussions/YMP7W4_9mjM

Use Native code to set the permission.

Comment: What i found strange is, when i add the built hint via the GUI, "\" ar added before ":" and "=" so afterwards in the settings.properties the hint is written like "<uses-permission android\:name\="android.permission.READ_CALENDAR".. But it wont work either