# android calendar crashes where iOS is working

Tags: codenameone

My app crashes with NullPointerException, since the android calendar does not return a Collection  of calendar names from the dc.getCalendars(); function from the CN1 Calendar Lib, even though it is working to this point on the iOS iphone version.

```
Device Calendar dc = DeviceCalendar.getInstance();
Collection<String> calNames = dc.getCalendars();
String [] nameArray = calName.toArray(new String[calName.size()]);
```

Its throwing me an NullPointerException for the 3rd line because calName is a null object and I cant use size() on it. Again, the code IS working on iPhone, so it seems there is a problem with android.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The javadocs for that method say that `getCalendars()` will return `null` if you don't have permission

https://github.com/sidiabale/codenameone-calendar/blob/master/CN1Calendar/src/com/codename1/calendar/DeviceCalendar.java#L91

You'll need to add the permissions using the `android.xpermissions` build hint.

```
 codename1.arg.android.xpermissions=<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALENDAR"/> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CALENDAR"/>
```

And it looks like you also need to set `android.targetSDKVersion=21`

See [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43089357/android-calendar-permission-issue) for a related issue.

Comment: Both build hints are set, as the thread you relate to was created by me. The app also says before installing, that it need access to the calendar, though when trying to get calendar names, it returns null. Anything other I might be doing wrong?

Comment: Looking at the source, it will also return null if the device doesn't have any calendars.

Comment: If have tested it on 2 Android devices now, S7 and Sony Xperia Z5, both inform the user about the need of access to the calendar before installing the app, when trying to access the calendar, both throw the Exception from above, while iOS actually lists the calendars of the device. There still seems to be something wrong with the permissions, I have checked options as well and the access to the calendars are set to true there for my app. What could be going wrong? As I said, both build hints are set.

Comment: As I said, it will return null also if there are zero calendars currently.  Guard against that NPE, just in case.  Use the API to check how many calendars the device has.

Comment: There are several Calendars on the S7 synced within the Samsung Calendar App, full with events. Could it be that the library is just not working anymore? On iOS the Library is only working to the point that it lists me the calendars, but when trying to read events it throws an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException within the library DeviceCalendar.getEvents() function.

Comment: I don't know...  Haven't used that lib.  I recommend posting an issue in the issue tracker for that lib on Github, and perhaps the maintainer will be able to help.